# What does it mean to be a brother to the old wild goose?

Tags: lyrics, meaning

I heard the song “Cry of the Wild Goose” by Tennessee Ernie Ford recently. One of the lines is:

> I am a brother to the old wild goose.

I was wondering what that means exactly. Does it equate a man's views on women to the mating rituals of wild water fowls?

Answer (score 1):

The song is about a man who is unwilling or unable to commit to a relationship with a woman, rather he stays for a while and then leaves. The analogy is to the migration of geese when the weather turns cold and then again when it's warm. The man is singing that his nature is migratory, like a wild goose, but he wonders if being able to settle down would bring him greater satisfaction.

---

As an aside, "The Cry of the Wild Goose" is

> a 1950 song written by Terry Gilkyson. Originally performed by Frankie Laine. (Wikipedia: [The Cry of the Wild Goose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cry_of_the_Wild_Goose))

Comment: Is it Glykerson or Gilkyson?